# Parsing Out an Arduino Server Message

Tags: string, parsing, server, arduino, client

I'm trying to parse out a message received from a sever where the Arduino is the client. The message consists of numbers and letters and is split based on spaces and ";" - such as "s112; 223; set; 32s ". When I run my code and the server send the message it prints a few blank lines and that is it. Here' the code!

```
  if (client.available()) {
char serverMsg = client.read();
String Msg = String(serverMsg);
String parsedMsg[50];
int r = 0, t = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < Msg.length(); i++)
{
  if (Msg[i] == ' ' || Msg[i] == ';')
  {
    if (i - r > 1)
    {
      parsedMsg[t] = Msg.substring(r, i);
      t++;
    }
    r = (i + 1);
  }
}
for (int k = 0; k <= t; k++)
{
  Serial.print(parsedMsg[k]);
}

}
```

Comment: what is client.read ?  did you check your code by assigning "s112; 223; set; 32s " to Msg instead of reading it from your interface? did you print the received Msg to make sure you receive what you expect?  you did not mention any basic debugging attempts

Comment: Sorry about that. client.read allows for the client (the Arduino) to read incoming messages from the server. I have tried by assigning the string to Msg and it printed out as I expected. I think I am having trouble where I convert char serverMsg = client.read(); to String Msg = String(serverMsg); as I think it only reads one character at a time that way and I am unsure of going about it any other way

Answer (score 0):

The output of

```
String Msg = "s112; 223; set; 32s "
String parsedMsg[50];
int r = 0, t = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < Msg.length(); i++)
{
  if (Msg[i] == ' ' || Msg[i] == ';')
  {
    if (i - r > 1)
    {
      parsedMsg[t] = Msg.substring(r, i);
      t++;
    }
    r = (i + 1);
  }
}
for (int k = 0; k <= t; k++)
{
  Serial.print(parsedMsg[k]);
}
```

is

```
s112
223
set
32s
```

Which looks like what you probably expect. So the issue is the input string.

Print the received string to find out if the issue is on the server or client side. I don't know what `client.read` is so I cannot help here.

If it works the same as Serial.read you'll only receive a single byte. That might be an issue here.

If that is the case you should define a char array of suitable size and read bytes into it. either as long as they are available or until the buffer is full. The convert that buffer into a string and do your thing.